# django way to redirect on timeout

Tags: python, django

I want to understand if the approach I've used to redirect to another page on timeout is a proper one, or if there is a more adequate way in Django.

This is my template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
 <h1>Thanks for visiting, come back soon!</h1>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = '/home/';
    }, 2000);
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

This is my urls.py:

```
url(r"^$", views.HomePage.as_view(), name="home"),
url(r"^home/$", views.HomePage.as_view()),
```

Would it be possible to combine the two lines in one? (I'm thinking of the "Don't repeat yourself" principle)

Comment: Which two lines?

Comment: In the urls.py, the two regex

Comment: You could write a regex that matches both, `r'^(home/)?$'`, but I think what you have now is more clear and readable.

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of the timeout is, though. Why not just use a `RedirectView` directly in your urls.py? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview

Comment: For the timeout in general? Or as implemented in JS?
I want the timeout, because it's usually what a user would expect (based on experience in other webpages) when they log out or log in. What I mean is, when they log in or log out they get to a page that confirms successful log-in/log-out, stays like that for a few seconds and then they are re-directed to the main page. Could that be implemented with RedirectView as well?